# .htaccess Redirect traffic from new domain to another folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have two domains pointing to the same server.

Domain A is my historical domain.

Domain B is a new domain and is an alias for Domain A. I have no hands on DNS configurations for that domain.

I want Domain B to point to a folder of my server (or a sub-domain of Domain A) using .htaccess

Thanks

Comment: "I have no hands on DNS configurations for that domain." - What do you mean by this? Obviously, without any DNS configuration "Domain B" will not function as "an alias for Domain A".

Comment: What I mean by that is that I bought the new domain on the host that already have my server and first domain. They have a feature to alias any domain to another managed by them, thus loosing access to the DNS zones management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainB\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/domainB/
RewriteRule ^ /folder/domainB%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

An alternative would be that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainB\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?folder/domainB(/.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,END]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainB\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /folder/domainB%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

Comment: That's perfect, many thanks !

Comment: Great that I could be of help. Now I want to ask a favor back: please take the time to actually understand that implementation instead of just blindly copying it. That is important. Thanks!